# Index/Match or VLOOKUP for Multiple Inputs and List of Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have my table with the inputs being Column1, Column2, Column3 and RangeVal. I want Shape1 and Shape2 to be Calculated based on a master table (image 2). The master table needs Columns 1, 2, and 3 to match an ALSO be within the given range for that line. For Example, if Column1, 2, 3 have values 1, 1, 1 respectively AND the RangeVal is between 200-1025, show Circle for Shape1 and Square for Shape2. I was able to get all of this without range (see below), but am having issues with adding the range to the formula. Also, if none of the criteria is met, it should say "No Shape Exists", although that is a simple If statement on top of it all I believe. Please help. Thanks! Hope this is enough info.

Current Excel Formula (without range included):

Shape1

```
=INDEX($K$2:$K$4,MATCH($A2&$B2&$C2,$H$2:$H$4&$I$2:$I$4&$J$2:$J$4,0))
```

Shape2

```
=INDEX($L$2:$L$4,MATCH($A2&$B2&$C2,$H$2:$H$4&$I$2:$I$4&$J$2:$J$4,0))
```

Table with Inputs:

[image]

Master Key Table

[image]

Comment: Are you entering the formula as an array with Ctrl-Shift-Enter?

Comment: Yes I am. The answer below is correct, but I have issues if I rename the Title of the Column Shape1 or Shape2 (table 2) because he used this in the formula. Trying to figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your provided sample data and setup, in cell E2 and copied over and down to F4 (can use this same formula for both columns):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$4,$A2,$I$2:$I$4,$B2,$J$2:$J$4,$C2,$M$2:$M$4,"<="&$D2,$N$2:$N$4,">="&$D2)=0,"No Shape Exists",INDEX($K$2:$L$4,MATCH(1,INDEX(($H$2:$H$4=$A2)*($I$2:$I$4=$B2)*($J$2:$J$4=$C2)*($M$2:$M$4<=$D2)*($N$2:$N$4>=$D2),),0),MATCH(E$1,$K$1:$L$1,0)))
```

Adjust range references to suit your actual data.  This does not require array entry.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I am curious, if I have a second data range (the real life scenario is current min/max and voltage min/max) where would I keep adding it into the formula? Hope that made sense...

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. Just continue with the *(column1 range in question)*(Column2 range in question). I will try it now.

Comment: I was able to add more to the formula. This is working great except that it relies on the column header "shape1" to match the table2 Column "shape1". What if I change table2 from Shape1 to "MyShapes" or something?

Comment: @SeanDon You can do this however you would like.  The suggestion I provided was based off of the sample data, and I figured this was a good way to do it all in one formula.  Some possible options available to you are: A) Split the formula into two, each one would look at a specific column.  B) Update the header in both locations.  C) Hardcode the headers to match instead of using cell references.